# jpa using a collection as a parameter for a IsContainingIgnoreCase query method

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

is it possible to use a List object as a parameter for a jpa query method such as shown below

```
List<String> aList = new ArrayList<>();
aList.add("test"); //and pretend there is a few more elements in the list.
repository.countDistinctByTitleIsContainingIgnoreCase(aList);
```

where the method is defined as:

```
int countDistinctByTitleIsContainingIgnoreCase(List<String> aList)
```

here is some additional information in query methods

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. What you can do is, to use a [`Specification`](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) to assemble your where condition.